# Gambling game always returns 1 rupee

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm at a late game stage. In the Lurelin village's chest gambling mini game, I always get 1 rupee no matter how many times I try. Save/load does not work either. Is there some mechanism or bug to cause the 100% failure rate?

I wonder if that's due to me having too many rupees (3000 atm).